# React JS: TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `Beach` component here that is throwing me the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
ResortDetail
C:/Users/JS/Desktop/MERN/KR/frontend/src/screens/Beach.js:33
  30 |           <p>{description}</p>
  31 |           <br/>
  32 |           <h4>Amenities:</h4>
> 33 | <div>
     | ^  34 | { 
  35 |                 Object.entries(amenities).map(
  36 |                   ([key, value]) => {
View compiled
▶ 17 stack frames were collapsed.
```

Basically the data looks something like this:

```
{_id: "2", name: "Bluewater Maribago Beach Resort", price_per_night: 4156,…}
address: "Buyong"
amenities: {tv: true, reservation: true}
city: "New York"
description: "Set in a complex of thatch-roofed buildings on the Cebu Strait, this posh beachfront resort is 1 km from Mactan Island Aquarium and 4 km from the Magellan Shrine."
email: "info@example.com"
image: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1507525428034-b723cf961d3e"
latitude: 10.290899
longitude: 124.000822
name: "Bluewater Maribago Beach Resort"
phone: "(032) 402 4100"
price_per_night: 4156
province: "California Road"
rating: 3.5
reviews: 35
website: "http://www.bluewater.us/"
zip_code: "6015"
_id: "2"
```

I think its complaining about the `Object.entries(amenities).map(` but not sure why and how can I fix it.

Here's the complete code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

const Beach = ({ match }) => {
     
     const [resort, setResort] = useState({})

     useEffect(() => {
        const fetchBeach = async () => {
            const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/resorts/${match.params.id}`)
            setResort(data)
        }
 
        fetchBeach()
     }, [match])
    
    const { name, address, city, province, zip_code, image, description, amenities, website, phone, email } = resort

    return (
        <div className="row mt-5">
            <div className="col-lg-7">
            <h1>{name}</h1>
            <p><FaMapMarkerAlt /> {`${address}, ${city} ${province}, USA, ${zip_code}`}</p>
            <img src={image} alt={name} width="700" />
            <br/>
            <p>{description}</p>
            <br/>
            <h4>Amenities:</h4>
  <div>
  { 
                  Object.entries(amenities).map(
                    ([key, value]) => {
                        if(value){
                            return <p>{key}</p>
                        }
                       return null
                    }
                )
               }
            </div> 
        </div>



        </div>
    ) 
}

export default Beach
```

Any idea how to fix this and pull to properly up the object amenities?

Comment: Is the issue maybe that you're returning `null` in your `map`? Or is it possible that `amenities` is null?

Comment: how do i map on the object amenities then?

Comment: `amenities &&  Object.entries(amenities).map(`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'amenities' is undefined in the beginning as it takes some time to fetch the data from your API. So your code ends up being Object.entries(null) and hence the error.
Place a check if amenities is not null before you use Object.entires() as shown below.

```
amenities && Object.entries(amenities).map(
                    ([key, value]) => {
                        if(value){
                            return <p>{key}</p>
                        }
                       return null
                    }
                )
               }
```

Hope it helps ! :))

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const Beach = ({ match }) => {
  const [resort, setResort] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchBeach = async () => {
      const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/resorts/${match.params.id}`);
      setResort(data);
    };

    fetchBeach();
  }, [match]);

  const {
    name,
    address,
    city,
    province,
    zip_code,
    image,
    description,
    amenities,
    website,
    phone,
    email,
  } = resort;

  return (
    <div className="row mt-5">
      <div className="col-lg-7">
        <h1>{name}</h1>
        <p>
          <FaMapMarkerAlt />{" "}
          {`${address}, ${city} ${province}, USA, ${zip_code}`}
        </p>
        <img src={image} alt={name} width="700" />
        <br />
        <p>{description}</p>
        <br />
        <h4>Amenities:</h4>
        <div>
          {resort
            ? Object.entries(amenities).map(([key, value]) => {
                if (value) {
                  return <p>{key}</p>;
                }
                return null;
              })
            : null}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Beach;
```